# don't and don't in the same sentence? What was the authors point?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, double-negation

Reading an article, I came across this sentence which I can't seem to make sense of. The author uses a double negative but I'm not sure what the point is. Could this just be poor grammar?

Here is the sentence: *"I don’t have some gene that others don’t"*

Sentence for full context: *I don’t have some gene that others don’t; I definitely haven’t been lucky.*

If anyone would answer and help me understand, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't have some unique / rare gene.

Comment: Wow, that's a clumisly worded sentence masking a poorly conceived notion.

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is "I don't have some gene that others lack", or "I don't have some gene that nobody else has", or even "I don't have some gene that others don't *have*" ... then, yeah, any of those would be clearer.  Clearer still would be cutting the reference to other people - something like "I don't have some super-rare gene."

Answer (score 0):

The author seems to be trying to say that he/she doesn't possess some unique quality that nobody else has. I agree that it's clumsily worded.